# Error from Valgrind: "Invalid write of size 8" and "Address ... below stack pointer"

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, darknet

I'm modifying Darknet code for additional implementation. So, I added many dynamic memory allocation codes to the source code. 
But, I found there are many memory leaks. So, I used Valgrind for check them.

But, there is unknown error message from Valgrind.

```
==29993== Invalid write of size 8 
==29993==    at 0x184550: gemm_nt (gemm.c:95)
==29993==    by 0x184B03: gemm_cpu (gemm.c:164)
==29993==    by 0x1843EF: gemm (gemm.c:71)     
==29993==    by 0x1690B7: forward_connected_layer (connected_layer.c:180)
==29993==    by 0x16654B: forward_network (network.c:614)
==29993==    by 0x16766B: network_predict (network.c:957)     
==29993==    by 0x11C6AB: validate_classifier_single (classifier.c:619)
==29993==    by 0x11E9C3: run_classifier (classifier.c:1371)   
==29993==    by 0x12BCF3: main (darknet.c:449) 
==29993==  Address 0x1ffeffea00 is on thread 1's stack    
==29993==  80 bytes below stack pointer 
==29993==
```

The error line just point to "{" that begin line of function "gemm_nt". But, I don't know why it point to this line.

```
void gemm_nt(int M, int N, int K, float ALPHA, float *A, int lda, float *B, int ldb, float *C, int ldc)
{ // <- error line pointed by Valgrind (line:95)
    int i,j,k;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i = 0; i < M; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j){
            register float sum = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < K; ++k){
                sum += ALPHA*A[i*lda + k]*B[j*ldb + k];
            }
            C[i*ldc + j] += sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I already checked about "out of bound error". As I check, they don't over the range of array.

Comment: `C[i*ldc + j] += sum;` is the only place in the function where the invalid write can happen. So the index `i*ldc + j` is out of bounds for the array `C`. This is all that can be said without seeing the rest of the code

Comment: Sometimes Valgrind doesn't point to the exact line of code which is trouble?

Comment: And, Is there a way to know the size actually allocated to C?

Comment: You'd have to look at the *calling* code to find out how the parameters to `gemm_nt` are allocated.

Comment: After I add a code line `printf("%d\n",i*ldc + j)`, Valgrind doesn't show the error message more... I don't know why... `C` is allocated before, by this code `l.output = calloc(batch*outputs, sizeof(float));`. The `batch*outputs` is same to `M*N`.